# How to get checkbox whose label value is known

Tags: jquery

I have some checkboxes that has UNIQUE values for their labels. I know the label value, how can I access checkbox.

Eg:

```
<input id="id1" type="checkbox">
<label for="id1">D2_Telecaller</label>
```

How to get this checkbox if I know D2_Telecaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it like below, this will work well when checkbox labels are unique, and of course they will be ;)

```
    // get table that has checkboxes
    checkBoxList = $("[id*=tblRoleList]");
    // Find all labels
    checkBoxLabels = checkBoxList.find("label");
    // Loop through all lables
    checkBoxLabels.each(function () {
    // If label text matched
    if ($.inArray($(this).text(), "D2_Telecaller") != "-1") {
       // Previous input must be associated checkbox
       chk = $(this).prev();
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector :

```
$("label:contains('D2_Telecaller')").prev("input")...
```

or

```
var text = 'D2_Telecaller';
$("label:contains('" + text +"')").prev("input")...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `:contains()` selector and `attr()` method. By the `attr` method we can access the value of `for` attribute which is related to the corresponding check box's id.

Refer this code snippets:

```js
var labelVal = 'D2_Telecaller';
var checkBoxId = $("label:contains('" +labelVal+"')").attr('for');
$('#'+checkBoxId).attr('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id1" type="checkbox">
<label for="id1">D1_Telecaller</label>
<input id="id2" type="checkbox">
<label for="id2">D2_Telecaller</label>
 <input id="id3" type="checkbox">
<label for="id3">D3_Telecaller</label>
```